# Braintree java SDK performance

Tags: java, performance, sdk, timing, braintree

I can't find any information regarding Braintree java SDK performance. In general, almost no information about Braintree throughput and timings at all.

Root issue: when we have customer's peak (about 100 at the same moment) and application tries to lookup all of them (`GET /customers/{id}`), operation timing goes extremely high.

Average time for the operation - about 1s. At the peak - up to 14s. I even don't know whether it's ok or not for Braintree.

Tried to find out some tuning options inside the SDK, but unsuccessfully. Looks like it uses only direct `HttpUrlConnection` with no pooling or something like that.

Any link will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I work at Braintree. Merchant performance varies greatly depending on how you are using our API, but you should contact our [support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) to ensure there isn't anything abnormal with your experience.

Comment: Ok, will gather more info and send. Thank you